# iBeacons configuration to identify from CoreLocation SDK

Tags: ios, core-location, ibeacon

I have a requirement to identify different retail shops using iBeacons. For that I need to buy the iBeacons from a Apple certified vendor and setup the beacon for UUID, Identifier, Min and Max.

I bought few iBeacons from StickNFind (https://www.sticknfind.com). But I have no clue how to retrieve these parameters from iBeacons.

Does anyone know this possible from other vendors? Or do we need to rely on vendor's SDK? I want to use Apple SDK for this and don't want to rely on other's SDK.

Answer (score 1):

any vendor that implements the beacon protocol is compatible with CL and provides the 4 basic attributes you describe

since the brand you refer to claims beacon compatibility: CL should work with there beacons too

Comment: But Im not able to do with the StickNFind (https://www.sticknfind.com) beacons I bought.

Comment: sorry - but they claim beacon compatibility so it should work with them too

Comment: maybe you need to ask sticknfind

Answer (score 1):

Apple only provides an SDK for detecting iBeacons.  It does not provide a SDK for configuring iBeacon identifiers on an external hardware device.  Each beacon vendor provides its own way of doing this. There is no standard.

To make things more confusing, some vendors do not allow you to reconfigure the identifiers at all.  I am not aware of any way to configure identifiers with StickNFind beacons.

My company's [RadBeacon](http://www.radiusnetworks.com/ibeacon/radbeacon/tag/) product allows you to use a free iOS and Mac app to easily configure beacon identifiers over the air using Bluetooth.  But because there is no standard, these apps only work with RadBeacon products.  Some other vendors provide their own configuration apps as well.

Comment: Thanks. I can see from your web site that we can configure the identifier for each beacon. But not the UUID. This is perfectly fine with us and this is what we are looking for. I think StickNFind doesn't allow to configure identifiers for their devices. Don't your company ship devices outside US? Or else can you recommend me few vendors who allows that? I searched. But still no luck.

Comment: And also I checked the UUID using "BLE Utility" iOS app and used "Locate" app to find the beacon. But its not showing it in the beacons list.

Comment: You absolutely can set the UUID on Radius Networks beacons -- it is just as easy as setting the major and minor.  And we do ship outside the US -- immediately in the case of the USB powered models and very very soon for the battery powered models (we were waiting on international certification for the battery models.)  If you need battery models shipped outside the US before the website is updated to allow you to order online, simply email sales@radiusnetworks.com

Comment: The reason you can't see your beacon in "BLE Utility" or "Locate" is because iOS requires you to pre-configure the known ProximityUUID of the beacon into the app before the beacon will be visible.  If you don't know the UUID, then this is a real problem -- unfortunately it  is a restriction of the operating system.  If you need to read an unknown ProximityUUID of a beacon, you can do so using an Android or OSX Mavericks device.  My company has apps that do both:  the iBeacon Locate app for Android and the ScanBeacon app for OSX Mavericks.

Answer (score 0):

There is a method in StickNFind SDK

```
– (BOOL) setIBeaconBroadcastDataAtIndex: (int) index proximityUUID: (NSUUID *) proximityUUID major:(uint16_t)major minor:(uint16_t)minor signalAt1m: (int8_t) signal;
```

is what you need.

To convert StickNFind Beacon to iBeacon first you need to connect to the SNF Beacon and then call *setIBeaconBroadcastDataAtIndex* by giving proximityUUID, major, minor and txPower values.